# Convert "√9-1" to "sqrt(9)-1"

Tags: python

I have a string like *"2+√√81.0-1"*. And I want to convert this string to *"2+sqrt(sqrt(81.0))-1"*. I have an algoritm doing this convertation:

```
import re

val = ["2", "+", "√", "√", "8", "1", ".", "0", "-", "1"]

find_sqrt = 0
for n, i in enumerate(val):
    if i == "√":
        val[n] = "sqrt("
        find_sqrt += 1
        continue
    if (re.match(r"\D[^.√]", i)) and (find_sqrt > 0):
        val[n-1] += ")" * find_sqrt
        find_sqrt = 0

if find_sqrt > 0:
    val.append(")" * find_sqrt)
    find_sqrt = 0

print(''.join(val))
```

But in output I have *"2+sqrt(sqrt(81.0-1))"*. For some reason, my regular expression does not see a “-” and skips it.

I need help to fix my reqular expression. And if you know an easier way to convert "√9-1" to "sqrt(9)-1" I will be happy for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use a stack for proper closing of parentheses.

```
val = ["2", "+", "√", "√", "8", "1", ".", "0", "-", "1"]
stack = []
result=[]
stackresult=[]
index=0
while(index<len(val)):
    if val[index] == "√":
        stack.append(val[index])
        for iterator in range (index+1,len(val)):
            if val[iterator] == "-": #check for all operator here (or all ops)
             while(len(stack)!=0):
                 stack_pop=stack.pop()
                 if(stack_pop=="√"):
                  stackresult.insert(0,")");
                  stackresult.append("sqrt(")
                 else:
                  stackresult.append(stack_pop);
             stackresult.reverse()
             result.extend(stackresult)   
             break
            else:
              stack.append(val[iterator])
            index+=1
    else:
        result.append(val[index])
    index+=1
print(''.join(result))
```

Read more: *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-python/*

Comment: I change my regular expression to `r"[^\.√0-9]"` and this code has worked. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is building a parser. Processing individual characters can only cover basic parsing requirement. For something like this you should use a Lexer so that a string like `45+32` would be split into

```
block1 - 45 - NUM
block2 - + - TOKEN
block3 - 32 - NUM
```

Using this operations can be performed contextually. Kindly see this page for detailed information:

[Parsing In Python: Tools And Libraries](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/)